# natural deduction with two quantifiers on both sides of the double implication

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, natural-deduction

I need help to understand step by step of the follow natural deduction

∃x∀y ¬α(x, y) ↔ ¬∀x∃y α(x, y)

I'm used to making natural deductions, but in this case they have two quantifiers on each side and I'm a little confused by the rules to apply

I would like to know how to proceed with the ∃ exclusion rules in this example.

Below are the last lines to explain the format of natural deduction i'm making.

```
          [∃x∀y ¬α(x, y)]                         [¬∀x∃y α(x, y)]            
                 ...                                      ...
           ¬∀x∃y α(x, y)                             ∃x∀y ¬α(x, y)
___________________________________I➔    ___________________________________I➔
    ∃x∀y ¬α(x, y) ➔ ¬∀x∃y α(x, y)          ¬∀x∃y α(x, y) ➔ ∃x∀y ¬α(x, y)
____________________________________________________________________________I↔
                        ∃x∀y ¬α(x, y) ↔ ¬∀x∃y α(x, y)
```

Comment: Your subgoal is to prove ∃x∀y ¬α(x, y) ↔ ¬∀x∃y α(x, y) or derive something from it?

Comment: prove by natural deduction

Comment: If you want ∃x∀y ¬α(x, y) ↔ ¬∀x∃y α(x, y) as the conclusion, you need two applications of I➔, the one you posted and the same thing in the other direction, then combine the two subtrees to ↔.

Comment: this final part is easy. I would like to know how to proceed with the ∃ exclusion rules in this example. Could you formulate?

Comment: You have to work... Left side: assume ∀x∃y α(x, y) and derive a contradiction. To do this, apply ∃-elim to the premise assuming ∀y ¬α(a, y) and use a with the previous assumption deriving ∃y α(a, y) and so on.

Comment: Can you help me to formulate the beggining? I'm also trying to adopt a bottom-up strategy to try to solve it, but it's difficult

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a form of natural deduction (screenshot from my proof checker)

[image]

Now, do it backwards to obtain the biconditional.